# Binding data from one data grid column in another data grid column

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a Xceed Datagrid control in WPF and I need the data from one column to be displayed in another column. My grid has 4 columns; **ProductID**, **ProductStatus**, **ProductIdentifier**, **ProductName**, and **VendorNumber**. Both **ProductID** and **ProductStatus** are hidden, but the data is there in the grid when I make the columns visible. I would like to merge the results of the **ProductStatus** and **ProductName** fields so that the status appears before the name in the same column, so it would look something like:

*New - USB-C Microphone*

*Out of Stock - USB Speakers*

The XAML that I have works correctly except binding the **ProductStatus** to the **ProductName** column.

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
    <xcdg:Column x:Name="ProductID" FieldName="ProductID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
    <xcdg:Column x:Name="ProductStatus" FieldName="ProductStatus" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
    <xcdg:Column x:Name="ProductIdentifier" FieldName="ProductIdentifier" ReadOnly="True" Visible="True" Title="Identifier" />
    <xcdg:Column x:Name="ProductName" FieldName="ProductName"  Width="*" ReadOnly="True" Visible="True" Title="Name">
        <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ProductStatus}" Foreground="{StaticResource Blue1Brush}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
    </xcdg:Column>                          
    <xcdg:Column x:Name="VendorNumber" FieldName="VendorNumber" ReadOnly="True" Visible="True" Title="Vendor" />
</xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
```

Could someone correct this such that the binding works?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind to an `ElementName` of an element in a different [namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) in a `CellContentTemplate`.

Try to set the `FieldName` property to "." and bind to both properties in the template:

```
<xcdg:Column x:Name="ProductName" FieldName="."  Width="*" ReadOnly="True" Visible="True" Title="Name">
    <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductStatus}" Foreground="{StaticResource Blue1Brush}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}" />
                </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
</xcdg:Column>
```

Comment: @Nse: Did you try this?